# Prevent unauthenticated users to view tutorials and images in coldfusion 2016 web application

Tags: coldfusion

I have a site that runs on ColdFusion 2016. To access it, user must login. None of the ColdFusion templates are accessible for unauthenticated users within secure directories. However, in some directories html templates, video tutorials and images can be viewed with direct link via url.

Is there way to restrict such access?

**UPDATE**
I added this code below but, it is blocking all access even from the link on pages. But, how to block non authenticated direct access?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="mp4" path="*.mp4" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sounds like a web server configuration issue, not a ColdFusion issue.

Comment: Any idea what setting? The server is Windows 2008 R2. Directory browsing is disabled.

Comment: Are these assets that can be accessed through a web server?

Comment: Edit the web.config file to deny users access.